# In great need of help on finishing python program

Tags: python

The "Component" argument for addCompnent() method is an instance of the component class. In short, Component has 2 arguments; "Component(self,name,methodCount)" As you see in my code, I added each Component to a list. What I need to do in validCount() is return the number of components where the methodCount != 0. From what I currently have my validCount() keeps returning 4 and I have no idea why. I have debugged it and still not seeing where 4 is coming from; especially when I initialize it to 0. Can you please point out what I am doing wrong? I have tried counting the Components that have 0 methodCounts and with none 0 methodCounts, but the numbers are not returning correctly either way. There are three classes in the whole program but here is just the one I'm having troubles with. (If needed I can post full cod):

```
class Effort(Component):

    addedComponents = []
    componentCounter = 0
    validCounter = 0

    def __init__ (self):
        return None

    def addComponent(self, Component):
        try:
            if (self.addedComponents.count(Component) != 0):
                raise ValueError
            else:
                self.addedComponents.append(Component)
                self.componentCounter = self.componentCounter + 1
                return self.componentCounter 
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Duplicate component")

    def count(self):
        return self.componentCounter


    def validCount(self):
        if (len(self.addedComponents) == 0):
            return self.validCounter
        else:
            for i in self.addedComponents:
                if (i.getMethodCount() == 0):
                    pass
                else:
                    self.validCounter = self.validCounter + 1
            return self.validCounter
```

Comment: Ask a specific question, please. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: can you specify what help do you need ? which part are you stucking in ?

Comment: My own `estimate_effort()` tells me that you should put more effort in asking this question. I will not down-vote but please remove the dropbox link and instead explain what you're trying to achieve *in the part that you have problems with*, what problems you hit, what literature did you consult etc. Basically prove that you put at least as much effort into exploring the issues as you expect the community to put into answering you.

Comment: I updated my question above, stating what Im trying to do, showing you what I have done, and what I have tried.

Answer (score 4):

A few comments.

1. Comment your code. Especially when you have mistakes, discerning *what* your code is supposed to do can be difficult for outsiders.
2. It's bad form to capitalize the "Component" argument to addComponent. Use capital letters for class names, lower case for parameter names. This code reads like you are trying to add the class type to the addedComponents, not an instance of the class.
3. Is validCounter supposed to be a class variable for Effort or an instance variable? If it's an instance variable, put its initialization in your init. If it's a class variable, refer to it as Effort.validCounter, not self.validCounter. Same for addedComponents and componentCounter.
4. Is validCount supposed to increment every call or return the number of addedComponents with methods? Assuming the latter, you don't need an instance variable. Either way, you probably want to re-initialize validCounter to 0 before your for loop.

Comment: ccoakley - Thanks for answering my question. After looking at it over and over I realized that was the issue and already changed the points you made in 3 and 4. I was actually coming back to comment to let everyone know I figured it out. I know my code my not seem as efficient as it should be I'm just beginning at the learning Python thing.

Comment: Efficiency isn't the biggest thing. But you'll find that certain conventions are regularly followed, and this has the effect that there are a lot of implied semantics in code. When you violate those conventions, other programmers get confused, even though the actual semantics (as interpreted by python) might not have changed. Since you are just learning, you do not yet know the conventions. Compensate for this with extra commenting. You might find that you appreciate it a year from now if you look back at your own code.